# How to use named parameters in a native spring-data @Query?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set up a db query using `spring-data-jpa` and a native query for a `postgres` database. But the following does not work. Why?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'public.my_table'::regclass", nativeQuery = true)
public int count();
```

Result:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:bigint, :regclass;]
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it: the `::` have to be escaped like `\\:\\:`